# How to get the height or width of an element in % as defined in css using selenium webdriver java

Tags: java, css, selenium, webdriver

How do I get the height or width of an element in % as defined in CSS using selenium webdriver Java?

Comment: Please share the html code for the webelement

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
String cssValue = driver.findElement(By.id("element_id")).getAttribute("style");
```

No this will extract all the css style part from your code for that element; then you can use String functions to extract required values

Answer (score 0):

you can use `getCssValue`

```
WebElement eleWidth = driver.findElement(By.id("element_id")).getCssValue("width");
WebElement eleHeight = driver.findElement(By.id("element_id")).getCssValue("height");
```

Comment: Won't work, through this you will receive height and width of your current screen resolution not  the element

Answer (score 0):

Try code like below:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class getSize {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://google.com");
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,15);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.className("gsfi")));
        Dimension dimesions=driver.findElement(By.className("gsfi")).getSize();
        System.out.println("Width : "+dimesions.width);
        System.out.println("Height : "+dimesions.height);
    }

}
```